# Changing the orientation of a user control (ProgressBar) in WP7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, user-controls, progress-bar

I'm using a progress bar in my app, this progress bar is defined inside the user control, e.g.:

```
UserControl x:Class="StirLibrary.ProgressBarControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="800">
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Margin="50,522,50,158">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Loading..." Name="loading" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Foreground="Green">
            </TextBlock>
            <ProgressBar Background="Transparent" Margin="10, 0, 0, 10" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Value="0" Maximum="100">
            </ProgressBar>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My problem is when the orientation of my app changes to landscape the progress bar's orientation doesn't change and this makes the app look ugly. Any suggestions how to avoid this and make the progress bar displayed as per orientation are welcome.

Comment: How are you displaying the user control? If it's in a PopUp then this is a known issue with the popup.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but perhaps you would consider using the ProgressIndicator that is handled by the OS and is a standard for displaying progress: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.progressindicator(v=vs.92).aspx. Otherwise I'd also consider looking at the PerformanceProgressBar from the Silverlight Toolkit that supposedly works better in some ways than the out of the box ProgressBar.

Comment: @Matt Am displaying the user control in a Popup.. and my problem is my whole solution has 3 projects UI part, Library part and scheduler part.. and this progress bar control is in Library part and am not able to access it in my UI part where am calling the event for orientation changed..  I know partial solution to my problem ..i.e, the stack panel that contains the progress bar must be rotated 90 degrees and (render transform origin) must be defined for the stack panel when orientation changes since i cant access the stack panel element am not able to implement what i know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt has mentioned above it is not possible to orient a pop up in user control because User control doesn't have any room for supported orientation. but since it was very crucial requirement for our App i found a work around and made few changes in the Main Page's class file and  the user control's class file.. the changes are:

```
 private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == PageOrientation.Portrait)
            {
ProgressBarControl.getInstance().ProgressBarControl_LayoutUpdated(this, e,e.Orientation.ToString());
}
else if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Landscape) == PageOrientation.Landscape)
            {
ProgressBarControl.getInstance().ProgressBarControl_LayoutUpdated(this, e, e.Orientation.ToString());
}
}
```

These are the changes in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ProgressBarControl : UserControl
{
    private static ProgressBarControl instance = null;
    public static Popup popup;

    private ProgressBarControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static ProgressBarControl getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new ProgressBarControl();
            popup = new Popup();
            popup.Child = instance;
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void ProgressBarControl_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e,string orientation)
    {
        if (orientation == "LandscapeRight")
        {
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { Rotation = 270 };
        }
        else if(orientation == "LandscapeLeft")
        {
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { Rotation = 90 };
        }
        else
        {
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0);
            ProgressPanel.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform { Rotation = 0 };
        }

    }

    public static void displayProgressBar(int requestId, int status, string msg)
    {
        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ProgressBarControl();
                    popup = new Popup();
                    popup.Child = instance;
                }
                popup.IsOpen = true;
                instance.loading.Text = msg;
                instance.progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;
                instance.progressBar1.Value = status;
            });
    }
    public static void dismissProgressBar()
    {
        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if(popup!=null)
                {
                    popup.IsOpen = false;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

and this what i have done in my ProgressBarControl.cs file (this is the user control's class file)

Xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StirLibrary.ProgressBarControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="800">
    <!--<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Transparent" Margin="54,406,50,320"></Border>-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ProgressPanel" Background="Black" Margin="54,406,50,320">
        <TextBlock Text="Loading..." Name="loading" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="32" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
        <ProgressBar Background="Green" Margin="10, 0, 0, 10" Height="33" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="351" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Value="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I could enable the orientation for my popup UserControl by simply adding to the Children of the main screen on top of which the Popup is being displayed as:

```
popUp = new Popup();
loginControl = new LoginPopup();  // this is the custom UserControl

popUp.Child = loginControl;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(popUp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class does not support orientation so you can't use this and expect it to handle orientation changes. This is regardless of whether the control displayed in the popup is in the same assembly or not.

Instead of using a `Popup` a simple alternative would be to put the control directly on top of all other content on the page. You could include this inside another control (such as a grid or a panel) if you wish.

Manually adding a RotateTransform to the control will give you the ability to add extra control over adjusting the orientation but I'd recommend not going down this route if you can avoid it.

Comment: I found a trick to do it :) and the orinetation works fine.. wil post the answer soon